# How to insert dynamic data to Neo4j using python

Tags: python, neo4j

i m new to neo4j and python my program will get nodes and relation as parameter and i want to insert that to neo4j
i m able to insert static data as follow

```
create(p:Person {name:"Hemanth"})
```

Here the "Person" will also Dynamically update

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Neo4j Python driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver).

Please have a look at this example https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-python-bolt.
In particular, you can read queries [here](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-python-bolt/blob/main/movies.py#L101-L108).
Replace it with the query you want and it should work.